# whats the best way to implement real time push messages with apache, php and mysql only?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

i'm trying to implement a chat application for android (where users can communicate people who are in same location). i'm thinking it of an facebook messenger with Geo specific oriented. i came across to terms like repeated pull, comet, bosh, websockects, socket programming, xmpp(which requires xmpp capable server like openfire) etc to do this. But my resources are fixed like apache, php (codeignter) and MySql only. I need to find the efficient to way to do this. Guys i need this. Please help me.

Thank you,
abbiya

Answer (score 7):

The preferred approach on Android is [**Google Cloud Messaging**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device.
>   This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data
>   to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a
>   friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data
>   (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly).
>
> The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and
>   delivery to the target Android application running on the target
>   device. GCM is completely free no matter how big your messaging needs
>   are, and there are no quotas.

Essentially, it works like this: **Your server talks to Google, and Google pushes the message in real-time** (or nearly so, as long as the device is powered on and connected to the Internet) to the Android device(s). There's a registration process that happens on the Android device the first time the app is installed (and at future points to revalidate the registration). **In your Android app, it's your responsibility to send this registration ID to your server so you can store it for future use.** Your server uses this registration ID when it wants to push a message to that device.

**The communication protocol between your server and Google is JSON over HTTPS.** Your server can use any languages/technologies, as long as it can communicate with Google's servers. A PHP/MySQL application can definitely meet the basic requirements for the service:

> Before you can write client Android applications that use the GCM
>   feature, you must have an application server that meets the following
>   criteria:
>
> - Able to communicate with your client.
> - Able to fire off HTTPS requests to the GCM server.
> - Able to handle requests and resend then as needed, using exponential back-off.
> - Able to store the API key and client registration IDs.

On the client side, **the Android device must be running API version 8 (Android 2.2) or later**. Of course, it's also your Android app's responsibility to process incoming messages (using a BroadcastReceiver, as the Android system sends an Intent to your receiver whenever a message arrives), which allows you to handle messages however you want.

Comment: for IM apps. using http is not a best practice. i am now using rabbitmq's pubsub to push messages to mobiles

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging is definitely the best practice for Android applications, including chat-type apps. Although technically GCM uses HTTPS, its performance is nothing like standard HTTP. The connection is established once and remains open forever, so there's no DNS or connection overhead each time you receive a message. GCM deals with a lot of the nasty internals correctly that others may overlook (security, redelivery, receiving when app isn't running, managing battery life, etc.). Lastly, GCM is **already running** on the phone anyway, so use it instead of making an extra connection.

Comment: i dont think its correct. its great that GCM deals correctly with the delivery of the messages. But the problem is while sending messages. from mobile you have to make http conn and from our server it has to make a http conn. It will load our server magnificently.

Comment: No, the point is that the connection on mobile is **already established** (it's "always on"), so you do not make any new connections on mobile. This makes it fast on the mobile side, not to mention less resource intensive. On the server side you do need to open a connection to POST messages to GCM, but I believe you can send multiple messages over one connection using the keep-alive features of HTTP.

Comment: the connection on mobile is already established to receive messages from gcm but to send a message you have to make a http req to your server

Comment: Now GCM supports the upstream messaging i.e client to server. Now it is possible for apps to send messages to app server through google ccs servers. App server has to connect to ccs server via xmpp protocol and process the messages.